# handle signal from Component.onCompleted

Tags: qt, signals, qml

I have two qml files in the same directory, main.qml and MyItem.qml. When the mousearea is clicked the message "clicked!" is successfully handled by onMessage main.qml. However the message "signal sent" is never retrieved/handled by main.qml. Why?

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
 width: 100; height: 100

 Loader {
    id: myLoader
    source: "MyItem.qml"

    Connections {
        target: myLoader.item
        onMessage: console.log(msg)
    }
 }
}
```

MyItem.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
 id: myItem
 signal message(string msg)

 width: 100; height: 100

 Component.onCompleted: {
   myItem.message("signal sent");
 }

 MouseArea {  
   anchors.fill: parent
   onClicked: myItem.message("clicked!")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `MyItem` is constructed before `myLoader`, so the `Connections` object hasn't even connected yet. You can see this by adding some print statements to the `Component.onCompleted` handler of each object:

#### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 100; height: 100

    Loader {
        id: myLoader
        source: "MyItem.qml"

        Connections {
            target: myLoader.item
            onMessage: console.log(msg)

            Component.onCompleted: print("Connections Component.onCompleted")
        }
    }
}
```

#### MyItem.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: myItem
    signal message(string msg)

    width: 100; height: 100

    Component.onCompleted: {
        print("MyItem Component.onCompleted")
        myItem.message("signal sent");
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: myItem.message("clicked!")
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
qml: MyItem Component.onCompleted
qml: Connections Component.onCompleted
```